# Seleniumbase Message: Element <p> is not reachable by keyboard

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, seleniumbase

I am trying to get to the following text area

[image]

But I get the error

```
Message: Element <p> is not reachable by keyboard
```

I tried both

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ql-editor p"))).send_keys(troll_list[rand_troll])
```

and

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='chat_send-form_textarea']/div[1]/div[1]/p"))).send_keys(troll_list[rand_troll])
```

And i get the same error

How do I get to this textbox using seleniumbase?
I am using the firefox driver.

UPDATE:

This behavior only occurs in Firefox. Chromium is able to find and select the textbox successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to enter text into `p` (paragraph) HTML tag which is not designed for that purpose.

You should either locate appropriate `<input type="text">` element or `<textarea>`...

Comment: Yesterday the <p> tag worked. (probably some update from admin). Selenium gui can still reach the textbox using the same css selector. For some reason, seleniumbase cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Add div to the css selector path.

> element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ql-editor p"))).send_keys(troll_list[rand_troll])

When using css selectors, add the tag name before the css path